Why is the telegram bot not responding?
I am writing a telegram bot response handler. To do this, I created a page in laravel
Route::get('url/tg', [BotController::class, 'tg'])->name('tg_index');

Then I write the following code in this method
public function tg() {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
        // created array
        if (!$data) {
            // Some Error
        } 
        elseif( !isset($data['update_id']) || !isset($data['message']) )
        {
            // Some Error output (request has not message)
        }
        else
        {   
               //helmet in response to the user's message
               $params = [
                'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
                'text'    => $data['message']['text'],
               ];
        }

        $token = '616340****:******NVqNNK93On-cT8TLtNMiZWE*****';


file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendMessage?'.http_build_query($params));
            
        }   

The web hook page
https://api.telegram.org/bot616340****:******FNVqNNK93On-cT8TLtNMiZWEO****/setwebhook?url=https://157.**.***.134/public/url/tg
Answer:

{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

There are no errors in the laravel logs regarding this code.
I do not receive a response from the bot when I write a message. What am I doing wrong?

Can you call your url in the browser? Is it found? There should be no public folder in Laravel urls - the public folder should be the project's "DocumentRoot"

@brombeer, I can open this page, but then an error is triggered there: "Undefined variable $params". There are pages in my project that also start with: 157...134/public/url/pages/, 157..**.134/public/url/answer etc. Does this affect my router for the bot?
